# The probability of interval intersect

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, combinations

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Suppose that the points $\{1,2,\dots,2n\}$ on the number line are randomly paired up to form $n$ intervals. Let the $i^\text{th}$ interval be $[a_i,b_i]$, for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. Find the probability that exists $i$ such that for all $j\neq i, [a_i,b_i]\cap [a_j,b_j]\neq \emptyset$.

In other words, find the probability that there exists one of the intervals which intersects all of the others.

I guess the result may be $2/3$, independently of $n$, is this right?

For $n=3$,  the possibilities for a single interval are equally likely to be each of the following:

$$
\left \{a_i, b_i\right \} \in\left 
\{ \text {{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{1,6},{2,3},{2,4},}\\
\hspace{3cm}\text{{2,5},{2,6},{3,4},{3,5},{3,6},{4,5},{4,6},{5,6}} \right \} $$

Comment: What is "a $1-2n$ arrangement"?

Comment: I don't know what a $(1, 2, \cdots, 2n)$ arrangement is either.  Why not just define what you mean?

Comment: @lulu Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Perhaps writing out an example would clarify the problem.  Say $n=3$.  Can you work the problem out completely in that case?  If so, edit your post to include that.  I'm guessing that $n=2$ is too small to tell us much.

Comment: @lulu I made a substantial edit, because I recognized that OP was trying to ask about this problem: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/RandomIntervals.shtml On cut-the-knot, they talk about randomly chosen points instead of \${1,\dots,2n\}$, but the problems are equivalent.

Comment: @MikeEarnest good find, and a very nice argument in the link.